# Custom rules do not create any issues after scanning source code using Sonarqube

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have created a set of Java Rules and packed it in a jar file using (Java plug in 3.13.1) as a dependency. Then added to the plugin path in my Sonar Qube 5.0.1 local installation($SONAR_HOME/extensions/plugins).
Now I was able to see the rules through the web interface. Then I run the sonnar-runner scanner (2.4) to test the issues generated to the custom rules. but after a successful execution there are no issues shown in the project through the web interface.
There are no errors or warnings in the sonar.log.
i have created custom profile using http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Writing+Custom+Java+Rules+101 steps.

I have below versions for plugins.

```
<sonar.plugin.api.version>4.5.7</sonar.plugin.api.version>
<java.plugin.version>3.13.1</java.plugin.version>
```

Comment: Do you confirm that you've added the rules to the profile in use?

Comment: side note but you should _really_ upgrade your SQ instance and java plugin version : there were great improvements on both.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam : yes, I've added the rules to the default profile. However, it is still not working.

Comment: @benzonico : do you have any working example with latest SQ instance and java plugin version?

Comment: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/plugins/tutorial/java-custom-rules-template

Comment: Have you set up your project to use the custom profile you are talking about ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue in the same sonar verison 4.5.7. The custom rules are visible in the profile and the profile is also mapped to the project I'm analysing. But sonar wouldn't show the error. The java plugin that I'm using is 2.4. will that be a problem? any hellp anybody much appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure  you're using same java plugin version :
1. in your "pom" - `<java.plugin.version>3.13.1</java.plugin.version>`
2. under $SONAR_HOME/extensions/plugins

Comment: Thanks Sonali. I was using different java plugin versions. I was not getting any error for this issue.